# AngularJS: Load content and replace exitng

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs

I am a beginner in AngularJS world (day 1st) and looking for some answers.

In previous projects I used jquery ajax to load the content into an existing HTML document, where the backend application returning a part of the HTML content if the ajax request is or an entire html document unless ajax request.

Example pagination: if a user clicks on pagination links, the server via Ajax back part of the HTML document, but if a user opens a link (?page=2) in a new tab will load a complete HTML document.

What interests me, is it possible to do similar with Angular?

I would like a similar thing, when the user feels the first time a website, it can show a complete HTML page, but when the user clicks on an internal link on that page, the content is loaded via AngularJS applications.

I would ask experienced users of AngularJS, for instructions, links to documents dealing with similar issues, "SO" answers etc.

Thanks.

Comment: this question is kind of broad but long story short: with angular you do the html rendering client side and you only retrieve the data from the server. For example you maintain a list in your controller and when the user clicks the second page you download the data from the offset and update your list and so the view will update too (via data binding).

Answer (score 0):

Fairly easy, we use this rather than the ng-html-include attribute, you'll need to include $compile in your angular directive.

```
$element.html(data);
var contents = $element.contents();
$compile(contents)($scope);
```